# SQL Query Involving Data From Different Tables

Tags: sql

I have two different tables with records I need to join together in a way I can't quite figure out how to make work. My data looks like this.

**Table A**

Columns: `Employee_ID, Employee_Department, Employee_Team, Manager_ID, Is_a_Manager` ... many other columns

Sample Values:

```
 12345    Department1    Team1    67890    Yes/No
.
.
.
```

One employee per row, several thousand rows comprising the entire company

**Table B**

```
Employee_ID, Manager_ID ... other columns
```

The exact same data set as Table A

Currently I'm combining those two tables (and three others) with a simple join on Employee_ID, which I'm then using as a data source in Tableau to visualize the data.

What I'd like to do with a SQL script is as follows:

1. Check to see whether an employee in Table A is a manager or not based on the `Is_a_Manager` column
2. If they are, find an employee in Table B who is one of their direct reports by matching the employee ID in Table A to the Manager ID in Table B.
3. Lookup that direct report's department and team in Table A by matching the `Employee_ID` in Table B to `Employee_ID` in Table A and displaying the `Employee_Department` and `Employee_Team` columns.
4. Add the direct report's department and team to two new columns in the original manager's Table A row

I'd like the final output in Table A to be something like

```
Employee_ID,  Employee_Department,   Employee_Team,  Manager_ID,  Is_a_Manager? ... Direct_Report_Department, Direct_Report_Team
```

Also, an important point is that some managers will have employees who are on different teams, so values in the Direct_Report_Department and Direct_Report_Team are not distinct.  I only actually need any one employee's Department and Team to display, it doesn't matter which employee's it is.

Finally, I am able to do step 1 fairly easily in Tableau, so if the SQL script could do steps 2-4 and simply return a null value if the employee was not a manager, that would work for me as well.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: That's a lot of questions in one question.  What have you attempted?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately I can't really share the exact code or more specific table values just because it's proprietary company information, so it's hard to give examples of what I've tried.  I'm new to SQL so I was hoping someone more experienced may be able to suggest a general approach to a solution; perhaps it's just a harder problem than I realized though. Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: You're not being asked to provide sensitive information.  You can make up your own sample data to demonstrate the issue and the expected results. As far as the code goes, it's hardly going to be proprietary if you're getting your answer from here!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work based on the requirement provided. You don’t have to do any of the steps in Tableau and can simply export the output from the SQL as your data source

```
Select Tb1.Employee_ID, Tb1.Employee_Department,   Tb1.Employee_Team, Tb1.Manager_ID, Tb1.Is_a_Manager, Tb3. Direct_Report_Department, Tb3. Direct_Report_Team
from Table_A Tb1
join (Select Manager_id, max(Employee_id) as emp_id from  Table_B group by Manager_id) Tb2
on Tb1.Employee_id = Tb2.Manager_id
left join (Select Employee_ID, Employee_Department as  Direct_Report_Department, Employee_Team as Direct_Report_Team from Table_A group by Employee_ID, Employee_Department, Employee_Team) Tb3
on Tb2.emp_id = Tb3.Employee_ID
where Tb1.Is_a_Manager = 'Yes';
```

Comment: It did indeed work.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great, please mark it as answered and upvote my response in that case. Appreciate your feedback!!